# Can I make the h:outputStylesheet to load css file that is being retrieved from servlet? (not resources folder)

Tags: jsf-2

Is it possible to tell the `<h:outputStylesheet` to load a file from servlet url ?

like `http://my.company.com/MyServletName/jahdkhasdhasjkdha8d98yuifysduifsdh` cause if I try something like

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css"
    name="http://my.company.com/MyServletName/jahdkhasdhasjkdha8d98yuifysduifsdh" target="head" />
```

where the

```
http://my.company.com/MyServletName/jahdkhasdhasjkdha8d98yuifysduifsdh
```

is a servlet that direct it to the right css file , it does not work... the `<link` tag is not being created

I need this cause when I'm trying to use

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://my.company.com/MyServletName/jahdkhasdhasjkdha8d98yuifysduifsdh" />
```

the `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}'/` expression inside the css file are not getting translated into WebApp Name...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Even when it has worked, it's the servlet who's responsible for EL resolving, not the `<h:outputStylesheet>` component.

You need to solve the problem differently. I'd start by just putting all CSS dependencies, such as CSS images, in the very same folder as the CSS file itself and then reference them relatively. This way you don't need to fiddle with the context path.

By the way, the `#{request.contextPath}` is shorter.

Comment: And the servlet CANNOT resolve the EL expression? cause when I include the css from local resource the expression are being resolved just fine

Comment: It's the `ResourceHandler` who resolves EL in CSS files and this is only invoked on `/javax.faces.resource/*` requests.

Comment: I meant to say, you have to manually resolve the EL in the servlet. You shouldn't rely the `outputStylesheet` on doing that.